# Replace "japanese" tag with "foreign language" tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

I just noticed that there is a tag named "Japanese". I suggest we delete it and replace it with a tag "foreign languages" or "non-English" or something.

Comment: Note that there is already a [tag:language] tag that pretty much serves that purpose.  If anything, I think [tag:japanese] should become a synonym of [tag:language].